# Tic Tac Toe in swift - Winning line

Tags: swift, if-statement

I followed a tut to help me build a tic tac toe game to keep learning Swift. In doing so I also wanted to add winning slashes for whatever combination that wins.

In my code I have

```
let winningCombinations = [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]
```

these are the buttons tags.

I have created labels that are just color bars with no text to be the slashes.
I connected them one as

```
@IBOutlet weak var lineFirstRow: UILabel!
```

then hid the label on the storyboard.

I have been trying things like

```
let lineRowOne = [0, 1, 2]

if lineRowOne = true {
 lineFirstRow.isHidden = true
} else {
 lineFirstRow.isHidden = false
}
```

I know this is not correct.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There are several wrong things with that `if`  statement. Firstly, `=` is used to assign values, you have to use `==` to check for equality. Secondly, how could an array of `Int`s be evaluated as a bool?

Comment: Perhaps you can get some ideas from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/tic-tac-toe-in-swift.

Comment: Sorry guys I am new to swift so I know my code was incorrect. I had a tic tac toe game that works when played, I was just trying to take it one step further and add a slash through the winning combinations. XmasRights code is the right one for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but I suspect your solution will be on something like this:

```
let winningCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]

let lineOne = [0, 1, 2]

if winningCombinations.contains(where: { $0 == lineOne })
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: That was perfect! How would I go about adding `let lineTwo = [3, 4, 5]` when I add it the code and switch it to `$0 == lineTwo` it doesn't change anything.